# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found while runtime call for that native method Eclipse

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, opencv

I am new in android programming so I tried to write just a simple program that can call jni folder native cpp file method from java.. Though I have tried to run OPENCV example and tried the same way to call but none of the m worked out not even OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing. It launch and crash in my emulator.

**com_rukna_myfirstandroidimageapp_MainActivity.h**

```
extern "C"{
 * Class:     com_rukna_myfirstandroidimageapp_MainActivity
 * Method:    getStringfromNative
 * Signature: (I)Ljava/lang/String;

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_rukna_myfirstandroidimageapp_MainActivity_getStringfromNative
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);
}
```

**CPPCALL.cpp**

```
#include <com_rukna_myfirstandroidimageapp_MainActivity.h>     
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>         
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_rukna_myfirstandroidimageapp_MainActivity_getStringfromNative (JNIEnv *env , jobject obj, jint src)     
{
        return (env)->NewStringUTF("HELLO from JNI CPPCALL !!");     
}
```

**using command prompt I also used this at MYProject/bin/classpath/ javap -s -p MainActivity

----I got many with this---**

```
public native java.lang.String getStringfromNative(int);    
  descriptor: (I)Ljava/lang/String;
```

**but when I call this method from my MainActivity like below**

```
package com.rukna.myfirstandroidimageapp;    
import library    
public class MainActivity extends Activity {   
/* some declarations and other functions */   
int a = 0;int b = 1;      
String s = getStringfromNative( a); /*---> error when call for the cpp method*/   
_field.setText(s);  
_field.setSelection(_field.getText().toString().length());  


public native String getStringfromNative(int a);

    static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            // Handle initialization error
        }
        else{
        System.loadLibrary("MyLib");}
    }
}
```

**I got the following error while running application:**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.rukna.myfirstandroidimageapp.MainActivity.getStringfromNative:(I)Ljava/lang/String;
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
#OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
#OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
# OpenCV
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC
include D:/OpenCV-2.4.11-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk


#LOCAL_MODULE    := CLAHE_test
LOCAL_MODULE    := MyLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := CPPCALL.cpp
#LOCAL_SRC_FILES := CLAHE_test.cpp
#LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

When I check in myproject.apk then I found under **MyFirstAndroidImageApp.apk\lib\x86**

```
libhydrogen.so
libimageutils.so
liblept.so
libMyLib.so
libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
libnative_camera_r4.1.1.so
libnative_camera_r4.2.0.so
libnative_camera_r4.3.0.so
libnative_camera_r4.4.0.so
libopticalflow.so
libtess.so
```

**Project Properties->C/C++ general-> Paths and Symbols-> Includes -> GNU C++**

```
${NDKROOT}/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
${NDKROOT}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/include
D:/OpenCV-2.4.11-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include
D:\android-ndk-r10d\platforms\android-19\arch-x86\usr\include
```

Help me as when I call same method without any argument then it runs normal I didn't get it why..... Do I need to give a constructor kind of thing if Yes then where and how?

Comment: I have tried first with call of same method with Mat file as argument then I tried to make it simple and tried for just long, int and so on.. But error was same. Without argument there is no error..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to modify APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a in Application.mk. Also, if the cpp is successfully compiled, you should find so file in libs/armeabi-v7a